# Returning 410 status code for urls containing certain string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've recently created with the help of stackoverflow a bunch of rewrite rules to 301 redirect urls that contain certain words or strings. The rules are like this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=Your_Account(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /suchen/? [L,R=301]
```

In this case, all urls that contain "name=Your_Account" are redirected to the search page. However, it is considered best practice to return a 404 or even a 410 status. A 410 would be better, since many of these urls were dynamically created and indexed by Google due to lack of no-index meta information. I could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=Your_Account(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /suchen/? [L,R=410]
```

But this would return a 410 error (gone) and a redirection, which is probably not valid. It works, the browser will not redirect the url, but I would prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SEO purpose 301 will also work fine.

Instead of `R=410` you use `G` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=Your_Account(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /suchen/? [G]
```

ALso `G` or 410 will not do full URL redirect, you need to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess, I can go with this solution. A 301 redirect might not be best practice in this case. Unfortunately, Google ist not very clear on this topic.